# NodeJS - Function executing three times

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

When the function is invoked it runs three times with both if and else statements being executed. However, the other functions are working fine where there are no 'if else' statements. So, How can I solve this?
This is the code:

```
**From todo.js**

    const tasks = require("./tasks");

    yargs.command({
      command: "Add",
      builder: {
        task: {
          demandOption: true,
        },
        deadline: {
          demandOption: true,
        },
      },
      handler(argv) {
        tasks.addTask(argv.task, argv.deadline);
      },
    }).argv;
```

```
**From tasks.js**

    //Add Tasks!!

    const addTask = (task, deadline) => {
      const tasks = loadTasks();
      const duplicateTask = tasks.find((taskk) => taskk.task === task);
      if (!duplicateTask) {
        tasks.push({
          task: task,
          deadline: deadline,
        });
        saveTasks(tasks);
        console.log(chalk.green.inverse("New task added successfully!"));
      } else {
        console.log("Task already exist!");
      }
    };

    // Load Tasks!!
    const loadTasks = () => {
      try {
        const bufferData = fs.readFileSync("tasks.json").toString();
        return JSON.parse(bufferData);
      } catch (e) {
        return [];
      }
    };

    //Save Tasks!!
    const saveTasks = (task) => {
      const saveTask = JSON.stringify(task);
      fs.writeFileSync("tasks.json", saveTask);
    };
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the functions `loadTasks` and `saveTasks`.  Without them we will not be able to reproduce your problem.  Also, it is possible that the error may be in one of these rather than in the code you have so far shared with us.

Comment: Added them @LukeWoodward

Comment: Sorry, but even with those functions added I still can't reproduce the problem.  Is there anything else in your `tasks.js` file?  Evidently you haven't included everything in this file, as you are missing `require` calls for `fs` and `chalk`.

Comment: Here is the Github link if you don't mind. https://github.com/Dhanush-ch/node-course.git

Comment: Please edit your question to include the missing code.  Please don't post links to off-site resources instead, because these can disappear.  In fact, I get a 404 error if I follow that link.